# R rbind multiple lists based on condition

Tags: r, shiny, rbind

I have 3 lists which I want to rbind based on condition (checkbox selection from RShiny). I do not want to write a lot of if else and feel there should be a better way of doing it

```
rbind(t1,t2,t3)
```

I get the checkbox selection in "typeSelection" and it can have "a b c" or any one based on selection. If "a" is selected on UI, I want to include t1 in my rbind, so on.

Comment: How about create a `switch` statement

Comment: Is there a better way other then using switch with all permutations

Comment: How is the UI selection appearing as an object? Is it a character vector? Maybe put `t1`, `t2` and `t3` in a list and then use `do.call(rbind, mylist[ui_selected_elements])`

Comment: `purrr::reduce`? We don't have a lot of information here to help in more detail